# Can I use "count" in Terraform to create an assume_role_policy from a list of account IDs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am setting up a resource in AWS which is to be accessed from other AWS accounts. The list of accounts that can access this resource is different based on the deployment (QA, Pre-Prod, PROD, etc.)

The list of accounts looks like this.

```
variable "my_list" {
    default = ["123456789", "111222333"]
}
```

Following is what I am expecting in the trust policy of the role.

```
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111222333:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to use count in Terraform on the `aws_iam_role` resource, but as expected, the count is creating multiple IAM roles.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trust policy to include multiple accounts should have `AWS` as the key for the principal but the value should then be a list of the ARNs for the root account. This is described in the [AWS user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html) and gives the two valid ways of specifying an AWS account: using the full ARN or just using the account ID. The example they provide looks like this:

```
"Principal": { 
  "AWS": [
    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root",
    "999999999999"
  ]
}
```

which would be part of a larger trust policy document that would look like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": { 
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root",
          "999999999999"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

To get the shorter style output then you can just use the `jsonencode` function ([Terraform 0.11](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#jsonencode-value-) or [0.12](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html)):

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "example_short" {
  name = "example-short"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ${jsonencode(var.my_list)}
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Or with the longer style with the full ARN for the root of the account:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "example_long" {
  name = "example-long"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ${jsonencode(formatlist("arn:aws:iam::%s:root", var.my_list))}
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: I have tried the second option and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Terraform 0.12.0 or later, you can construct the IAM policy document as a data structure and use `jsonencode` to format it to the string format that `aws_iam_role` is expecting:

```
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          for acct in var.my_list : "AWS" => "arn:aws:iam::${acct}:root"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
```

For Terraform 0.11 or earlier, there is no direct way to achieve this.

Comment: While it's not possible to do exactly what the OP wants as an output in 0.11, this is not really what you want for the trust policy (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html) and instead you want a list output so jsonencode is enough to do this and so will work in 0.11.